# Set React Color Value to Certain Parts of SVG

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg

Is it possible to set my dynamic primary color from ReactJS unto a specific class of the SVG? If so, how do I implement it?

**Error.svg**

```
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 26.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 500 500" style="enable-background:new 0 0 500 500;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    ....
    .st9{fill:#E0E0E0;}
    .st10{display:inline;}

    <!-- Primary -->
    .st11{fill:#CA0B00;} <--- Here is the color that I want to be able to change dynamically
    <!-- Primary -->

    .st12{opacity:0.9;fill:#FFFFFF;}
    .st13{fill:#263238;}
    ....
</style>
....
</svg>
```

**App.js**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import Error from "./Error.svg";

const App = () => {
   const [primary, setPrimary] = useState("#FFFFFF");

   useEffect(() => {....},[]); <--- sets the color for the primary 

   return <img src={Error} />
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a tool like [SVGR](https://react-svgr.com/playground/) to convert the SVG into a React Component, which is just a functional component that returns the SVG in your JSX. You can pass the color in as a prop and simply assign it to the appropriate attribute such as `fill`.

The working example below is a simplified version of the sample code you provided.

You can use the **Re-render** button in this example to see the effect in action. It triggers an `onClick` handler that sets the state `primary` to a random color, which gets passed as a prop to the SVG component.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const SvgComponent = (props) => (
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height={140} width={500}>
    <path className="my-target-class" fill={props.color} d="M0 0h300v100H0z" />
  </svg>
)

const colors = ["#7FFF00", "#ADFF2F", "#FF0000", "#00FF7F", "#00FF7F"];

function App() {
  const [primary, setPrimary] = useState("#7FFF00");

  console.log("color is: ", primary);

  const handleClick = () => {
    const color = colors[ Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length) ];
    setPrimary(color);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={(handleClick)}>Re-render</button>
      <SvgComponent color={primary} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-svg-component-with-color-prop-8hk68j